# How do I select distinct values between two dates

Tags: c#, sql

I am selecting two records between two dates, when doing this i am experiencing repeated record, I have used the word distinct but its not working: This is how my query looks:

```
public List<i> searchTwoDates(string firstDate, string secondDate)
{
    DateTime fdate = Convert.ToDateTime(firstDate);
    string realfirstDate = fdate.ToLongDateString();

    DateTime sdate = Convert.ToDateTime(secondDate);
    string realsecondDate = sdate.ToLongDateString();

    List<i> date = new List<i>();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(....);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT distinct * From TableName WHERE Cast(columnName AS DATE) > @columnName AND CAST(columnName AS DATE) < @columnName1 ORDER BY columnName1 Desc", conn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnName", realfirstDate);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnName2", realsecondDate);

    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Mod d = new Mod();
         here i get my column names....
        date.Add(d);
    }
    conn.Close();
    return date;
}
```

I also have a unique ID in my database so we can use that to retrieve unique record but how would i write that?

Currently i am getting repeated records

```
ID  FName sName Date
1   John  JAck  2013-9-07
2   Linda Bush  2013-10-07
3   Linda Bush  2013-11-07
This is what i want
ID  FName sName  
1   John  JAck  2013-9-07
2   Linda Bush  2013-11-07
```

This is the records between 2013-9-07 to  2013-11-07. in between these records i dont want any repeated ID

Comment: are you store datetime as string in the database?

Comment: I am storing it as Datetime - but here i am converting so its should be fine

Comment: What is the `d` variable? It's not initialized anywhere.

Comment: Can you provide sample table & required output?

Comment: I see you updated your question but it's still not clear. Based on what criteria did you select those two rows out of those three? And anywhay, you say you have a unique ID, how can that be repeated? What do you have in your database in the first place?

Comment: I read your new update. So you have Linda twice, and you only want to get this row once, right? That part is clear. But what about the date? If there are two rows with different dates, which one do you want to get?

Comment: Date i dont care it can repeat many time as it wants (i dont want sql to select unique date) but it should only get unique records. So a person select date1 and date2 he will be presented with list of records but a persons's fname and sname should not be repeated.

Comment: What about `select distinct id, fname, sname from table`? If you don't need the date, then this will work, no repetitions.

Comment: @fejesjoco your idea worked. Thank you

Comment: I'll post that as an aswer then.

Comment: See comments below as to why DISTINCT is not a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[migrated from comments]

You should use `select distinct id, fname, sname from table`. If you don't need the date, then this will work, no repetitions.

Comment: This doesn't work unless you select only fname and sname as there are distinct ID and Date fields. See below @user911

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select Max(ID),FName,sName,Max(Date)
FROM Table1
Where Date > 'SomeDate' And Date < 'SomeDate'
Group By FName,sName
```

Comment: using this, a user wont be able to select two dates?

Comment: It will give result as you expected you can use Between keyword to select between two dates

Comment: i've tried in my database and it works but when it come to c# it stops inside while(reader.Read()) i get error saying indexoutofrangeexception was unhandled by user code on ID. Do i have to specify ID somewhere? this is how my query looks `Select Max(ID),FName,sName,Max(Date) FROM Table1 Where Date > @Date1 And Date < @Date2 Group By FName,sName`

Answer (score 0):

Don't try using `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,FName,sName,Date
FROM Table1
WHERE Date BETWEEN 'Date1' And 'Date2'
```

**UPDATE**

Because of the two different dates and IDs in the question above you should use grouping. This gives you:

```
SELECT MIN(ID),FName,sName, MIN(Date)
FROM Table1
WHERE Date BETWEEN 'Date1' And 'Date2'
ORDER BY ID
GROUP BY FName,sName
```

`DISTINCT` will not work as there are different IDs and dates for each record.

The above query will give you the first occuring ID. You can change the `ORDER BY` to Date to get the earliest. Or you want the most recent then use `MAX` instead of `MIN` and use `ORDER BY` with `DESC`.

Comment: I still get repeated records Fname and Sname

Comment: What happens if you add DISTINCT as above?